# Writing a function to add rows to a data frame

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a function that will automatically add an empty row to the end of a data frame and assign the resulting data frame to the original name.

As an example, I've created the empty data frame `data` using:

```
data <- data.frame(id = integer(0), name = character(0))
```

I can add a row to `data` using single-bracket subsetting to assign `NA`s to all variables for the new row:

```
data[nrow(data) + 1, 1:ncol(data)] <- NA
```

This returns the same data frame with an additional row of `NA`s:

```
> data
  id name
1 NA <NA>
```

Running it twice proves the code-snippet is functioning:

```
> data <- data.frame(id = integer(0), name = character(0))
> data[nrow(data) + 1, 1:ncol(data)] <- NA
> data[nrow(data) + 1, 1:ncol(data)] <- NA
> data
  id name
1 NA <NA>
2 NA <NA>
```

The problem arises when I try to wrap this code in a function:

```
add_row <- function(df) {
df[nrow(df) + 1, 1:ncol(df)] <- NA
}
```

Calling `add_row()` returns no errors, but does not add a new row to the data frame:

```
> add_row(data)
> data
[1] id   name
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Clearly I'm missing something, but I'm not sure what it could be. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have to return the data frame from your function and then you can assign the result of the function to a new data frame or assign it back tot he original data frame overwriting it.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck if I understand you correctly, you're saying I need to add `return(df)` to the body of `add_row` and then assign the output to data.

Is there no way for the function to overwrite the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### A. Functional approach

Return `df` and then assign it to a new data frame or overwrite the existing one:

```
add_row <- function(df) {
  df[nrow(df) + 1, 1:ncol(df)] <- NA
  df
}

data <- add_row(data)
# or
data2 <- add_row(data)
```

### B. In place

#### 1. Pass name and environment

You can overwrite it from within the function but it's not the functional style that is generally used with R which emphasizes side effect free processing.

```
add_row_name <- function(df, envir = parent.frame()) {
  dfx <- envir[[df]]
  dfx[nrow(dfx) + 1, 1:ncol(dfx)] <- NA
  envir[[df]] <- dfx
  invisible(dfx)
}

add_row_name("data")
```

#### 2. Pass formula

or specify the name using a formula:

```
add_row_fo <- function(formula, envir = environment(formula)) {
    add_row_name(all.vars(formula), envir)
}

add_row_fo(~ data)
```

#### 3. Non-standard evaluation

Another possibility is to use non-standard evaluation:

```
add_row_ns <- function(df, envir = parent.frame()) {
  nm <- deparse(substitute(df))
  dfx <- envir[[nm]]
  dfx[nrow(dfx) + 1, 1:ncol(dfx)] <- NA
  envir[[nm]] <- dfx
  invisible(dfx)
}

add_row_ns(data)
```

### C. rbind

Above we based the code on that in the question but note that

```
rbind(data, NA)
```

would be sufficient to add an NA row provided you assign that back to `data` or to a new name so maybe you don't need `add_row` in the first place.

### Update

Fixed.  Added additional alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

You need to slightly modify your code as follows:

```
add_row <- function(df) {
  df[nrow(df) + 1, 1:ncol(df)] <- NA
  return(df)
}

data <- add_row(data)
```